# GPU and missing kernel...32b works but not 64b

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, windows

So I just did a build with an ASUS GTX 980 ti with windows 7 64b OS. None of the 64b versions of Blender are working, they just flash a quick command window for a 1/2 sec and then nothing. The 32b versions seem to work ok but I can't use the GPU to render because I seem to be missing the kernel 5.2. I've looked up as much as I can to try and fix this but I am coming up short. The 32b versions don't have a kernel_50 that I can rename, which seems to be the solution for the 64b version. Any body got any ideas?